# Magento 2.3 Layered Navigation Returns all Products, unfiltered

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, filter, magento2.3

I have set up a store with demo products, installed the Porto, which uses MagePlaza layered navigation.

However, when I use the layered navigation to filter the products down, it always returns all products in that category.

Assuming it was either Porto or the MagePlaza extensions, I disabled both, only to find that the actual core of the Magento system was ignoring the selected filters in the built-in layered navigation also.

I imported 20 products via an online migration tool, from Shopify and have also added products manually. Both seem to be affected by the problem.

The layered navigation module itself behaves as it should, in so much as it generates the correct numbers of products and loses filters that should disappear as other are selected (as attributes are set as filterable with results).

Has anyone seen this behaviour before or know of where to start when it comes to debugging the issue?

Thanks